# 18 seconds of idle time before PHP to execute

Tags: php, hosting

I'm absolutely at my wits end. I've taken over the development of a website which was build using the Symfony framework. However, running on my dev server (8GB 4CPU VPS NGINX) certain requests take an incredible amount of time. About 20 seconds.

Using Sentry for profiling it appears as if there is a large portion of idle time before index.php is executed.

[Sentry Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRTzG.png)

The odd thing is, this only appears to happen for requests that have to go through the API Platform framework. Requests using the EasyAdminBundle are executed almost instantly.

Any suggestions on what might solve this are much appreciated. Hosting PHP definitely isn't my field of expertise.

I've made changes to the FPM-PHP php.ini. I've tried changes to OPcache. Increased the fastcgi_buffer sizes. Added Redis to Symfony. Made sure Symfony is running in prod with APP_DEBUG set to 0. There hasn't been even the slightest improvement.

Comment: Maybe the cache directory is too full which also can slow down a lot. Look if you have a `clear:cache` command in symfony you can run.

Comment: Check your NGINX configuration for any possible misconfigurations, especially regarding the FastCGI parameters. And ensure that NGINX is properly configured to handle PHP-FPM requests efficiently.